# Select text-align center with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have a bootstrap framework, and select width dynamic:
**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectCenter">
   <option data-ng-value="20" value="20">20</option>
   <option data-ng-value="50" value="50">50</option>
   <option data-ngvalue="100" value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

**CSS bootstrap**

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

I have tried with css:

```
#selectCenter {
   text-align: center;
}
```

But It doesn't works.
Can I center text in select only with css?

Comment: Hello, I 'have tried but doesn't works, I believe it is a my custom css the problem, because I have used a part of materializeCss and maybe can be this

Comment: Try this:
`select { text-align-last: right; }`

Answer (score -2):

Your code works fine , You can simply fix this with `text-align:center` try with snippet

```css
#selectCenter {
   text-align: center;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="selectCenter">
   <option data-ng-value="20" value="20">20</option>
   <option data-ng-value="50" value="50">50</option>
   <option data-ngvalue="100" value="100">100</option>
</select>
```